# Laminate Flooring For a Laundry Room

Tags: flooring

I am in the process of remodeling my laundry room. Next step is to replace the flooring.

Currently the flooring is old one sheet vinyl glued down on concrete. I want to find out the feasibility of using click together laminate flooring in this application. Note that there will be full size washer and dryer sitting on top of the laminate flooring. Is that recommended or should this be avoided?

Let me add here that I am not asking about the type of vinyl flooring that has engineered plywood, MDF or hard fiberboard on the bottom.

Or would I be better off in this application to use a product like a peel and stick vinyl planking. (The place I work at recently replaced all their floors in hallways, entrances and high traffic areas with something like this).

Answer (score 1):

You want either a pure vinyl plank or a [WPC vinyl plank](https://www.builddirect.com/r/Vinyl-Flooring/WPC-Waterproof?N=fCla-fG4S-kjJT-nTD6) .   No affiliate to the link.   Just where I get close to 90% of my wood or vinyl flooring (I only get tiles locally due to variations).   But they will send you samples.   Also the orange big box has a house brand that is pure vinyl that is pretty good too.

When selecting size does matter.   Try wider planks and you want thicker.   These are all click lock and the thicker vinyl's click lock just works better - I am generalizing here but its true.

Most that I have used explicitly say no pad or anything under.   The theory is you do not want moisture trapped and a pad might cause issues with the locking mechanism.   The WPC variety goes into any basement bathroom I do unless someone makes me tile.

Another note.   Make sure it says "Waterproof" not water-resistant.   Get a sample and let it sit in a bucket of water for 2-3 days.   If it is made right it shouldn't even be phased and you dry it off in 30 seconds.   I tend to get dark grey or brown wood like planks and I everyone that sees them thinks they are super high-end.   Installs with a utility knife too.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid laminate floors totally in a wet room like a laundry or kitchen unless it's made of a material that is totally waterproof.  A simple leaky hose on a washer could turn into replacing the whole floor rather than a $10 fix and a few minutes of mopping.

I would look at the lock together vinyl plank flooring.  Some of it is price competitive with laminate, and some also gives you great waterproofing.  If the sheet vinyl is in good shape, you may be able to go right over it without removal, but that will depend on the manufacturers instructions.  You would probably have better luck with a thicker product if going over an existing floor.

Comment: I was actually looking at the "totally water proof" click together type planking. The stuff that is installed in a floating manner. I may have misused the term laminated. Do you think that stuff can stand up to having a washer and dryer sitting on it? The typical product I see claims to have a 0.028 protective top layer on it.

Comment: I think it can handle the weight, but you’ll want to make sure the washer feet are in good shape.  The plastic or rubber can be damaged, and then it won’t take long for the washer to run a hole through any protective layer.  There are so many things that fall under the “laminate” umbrella these days.  I still assume a compressed wood material with a printed top layer.